# mongodb: WriteError: code=17041, message='$anyElementTrue's argument must be an array, but is null'

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

When sending a request (update with aggregation pipeline) to MongoDB, I get an error:

**Write operation error on server localhost:52851. Write error: WriteError{code=17041, message='$anyElementTrue's argument must be an array, but is null', details={}}.**

But all the arguments of `$anyElementTrue` selector are not null.

Please help me to find the decision.

Mongo version is 4.2

Request:

```json
db.deviceGroupSettings.updateOne(
    {
        "$and": [
            {
                "deviceId": "2C51145D-5127-42F5-B9F6-D4087C50905A"
            },
            {
                "bioProfiles.profileId": {
                    "$all": [
                        "ZEuku"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    [
        {
            "$set": {
                "permissions": {
                    "$cond": [
                        {
                            "$anyElementTrue": [
                                {
                                    "$map": {
                                        "input": "$permissions",
                                        "in": {
                                            "$and": [
                                                {
                                                    "$eq": [
                                                        "$$this.profileId",
                                                        "jvPTn"
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "$eq": [
                                                        "$$this.account",
                                                        "JXFGG"
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "$map": {
                                "input": "$permissions",
                                "in": {
                                    "$mergeObjects": [
                                        "$$this",
                                        {
                                            "$cond": [
                                                {
                                                    "$and": [
                                                        {
                                                            "$eq": [
                                                                "$$this.profileId",
                                                                "jvPTn"
                                                            ]
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "$eq": [
                                                                "$$this.account",
                                                                "JXFGG"
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "permissions": {
                                                        "$setUnion": [
                                                            {
                                                                "$filter": {
                                                                    "input": "$$this.permissions",
                                                                    "cond": {
                                                                        "$and": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "$not": {
                                                                                    "$in": [
                                                                                        "$$this",
                                                                                        [
                                                                                            "XrFEm",
                                                                                            "pygfX",
                                                                                            "IVfKG"
                                                                                        ]
                                                                                    ]
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        ]
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            },
                                                            []
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    "smartAppAccess": {
                                                        "$setUnion": [
                                                            {
                                                                "$filter": {
                                                                    "input": "$$this.smartAppAccess",
                                                                    "cond": {
                                                                        "$and": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "$not": {
                                                                                    "$in": [
                                                                                        "$$this",
                                                                                        [
                                                                                            "UcrHQ",
                                                                                            "iKjTX"
                                                                                        ]
                                                                                    ]
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        ]
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            },
                                                            []
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {}
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "$concatArrays": [
                                "$permissions",
                                [
                                    {
                                        "profileId": "jvPTn",
                                        "account": "JXFGG",
                                        "permissions": [],
                                        "smartAppAccess": []
                                    }
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
    );
```

**========> ADDITION 1:**

Document structure:

```kotlin
data class DeviceGroupSettings(
    val deviceId: String,
    val bioProfiles: Collection<BioProfile>,
    val permissions: Collection<ProfilePermission>,
    val group: DeviceGroup,
)

data class DeviceGroup(
    val groupId: String,
    val accounts: Set<String>,
)

data class ProfilePermission(
    val profileId: String,
    val account: String,
    val permissions: Set<String>,
    val smartAppAccess: Set<String>,
)

data class BioProfile(
    val profileId: String,
    val account: String,
    val createdBy: String,
    val name: String,
    val userpic: String,
    val confirmed: Boolean,
    val confirmedBy: String,
    val profileAge: ProfileAge,
)
```

Comment: Can you please add structure of your data in Mongodb.

Comment: Hi Rachit! Please have a look at addition 1 in the head post